# How to ensure AWS Instance reachability?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I created an AWS instance (free tier) and attached this instance to an EIP. It functioned smoothly for the first few days. Then I stopped the instance for a few days and turned it back on. Then onwards, I get a '1/2 checks passed' message in the status checks column. To be specific, the instance reachability check fails. As a consequence, I have to disassociate EIP and Re-associate each day to ensure that the instance is reachable.

We are using this instance to run Moodle for our department on a trial basis. It is very embarrassing when students come to you each day complaining that the site is down. Could you please help me troubleshoot this problem?

Comment: you might need to check this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27278250/elastic-ip-needed-to-be-re-associated-after-stop-start

Comment: Hi There, the issue I have encountered is a little different. For me, the EIP disassociation happens every couple of days. Thanks for the suggestion. I am also able to re-associate each time.

Comment: I ran the EC2Rescue for Linux utility, found the problems, and fixed them.